# Why HotChocolate does not use the input typename instead of described type name?

Tags: .net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I have the following mutation in my schema which uses `DocumentGraphQlInput` as input type. But when I take a look at the schema in StrawberryShake I see that the type name is used (with `Input` suffix) which is described as `DocumentGraphQlInput`.

What I describe below is the right behaviour and my expectations a wrong, or this is a bug?

It looks like to me HotChocolate goes back to the registered type (in this case `DocumentInputContract` with `Input` suffix, so it will be `DocumentInputContractInput`) instead of using the name it is registered which is `DocumentGraphQlInput`.

HotChocolate does the same to the return type. I registered `DocumentOutputContract` as `DocumentGraphqlOutput` (see the code below), but in StrewberryShake the return type is `DocumentOutputContract`, however, in my opinion, it should be `DocumentGraphqlOutput`.

```csharp
public class AddDocumentMutation : ObjectTypeExtension<Mutation>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Mutation> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor
            .Field("addDocument")
            .Type<NonNullType<DocumentGraphqlOutput>>()
            .Description("Recording new documents in the system")
            .Argument("newDocument", arg => arg.Type<NonNullType<DocumentGraphqlInput>>())
            .ResolveWith<DocumentResolvers>(documentResolvers => documentResolvers.AddAsync(default, default));
    }
}
```

The resolver:

```csharp
    public async Task<DocumentGraphqlOutput> AddAsync(
        IResolverContext resolverContext,
        IDocumentService documentService)
    {
        DocumentGraphqlInputType newDocumentGraphqlInputType =
            resolverContext.ArgumentValue<DocumentGraphqlInputType>("newDocument");
        return await documentService.AddAsync(newDocumentGraphqlInputType);
    }
```

Where `DocumentGraphqlInput` looks like below:

```csharp
public class DocumentGraphqlInput : InputObjectType<DocumentInputContract>
{
    protected override void Configure(IInputObjectTypeDescriptor<DocumentInputContract> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor
            .Field(f => f.Id)
            .Description("Unique identifier of the entity")
            .Type<NonNullType<LongType>>();

        descriptor
            .Field(f => f.Name)
            .Description("Name of the entity")
            .Type<NonNullType<StringType>>();

        descriptor
            .Field(f => f.Description)
            .Description("Description of the entity")
            .Type<StringType>();

        descriptor
            .Field(f => f.Uri)
            .Description("The source url of the document")
            .Type<StringType>();
    }
}
```

But, StrawberryShake shows this:

```
type Mutation {
  """
  Recording new documents in the system
  """
  addDocument(newDocument: DocumentInputContractInput!): DocumentOutputContract!
}
```

However, it should be, I think, rather this:

```
type Mutation {
  """
  Recording new documents in the system
  """
  addDocument(newDocument: DocumentGraphqlInput!): DocumentGraphqlOutput!
}
```

The `DocumentGraphqlOutput` describes `DocumentOutputContract` like this:

```csharp
public class DocumentGraphqlOutput : ObjectType<DocumentOutputContract>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<DocumentOutputContract> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor
            .Field(f => f.Id)
            .Description("Unique identifier of the entity")
            .Type<NonNullType<FloatType>>();

        descriptor
            .Field(f => f.Name)
            .Description("Name of the entity")
            .Type<NonNullType<StringType>>();

        descriptor
            .Field(f => f.Description)
            .Description("Description of the entity")
            .Type<StringType>();

        descriptor
            .Field(f => f.Uri)
            .Description("The source url of the document")
            .Type<StringType>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is it getting the `DocumentOutputContract` type? What does `documentResolvers.AddAsync` return?

Comment: @MichelFloyd I updated the question and hopefully it answers your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small example to observe what is happening here. It seems what I described is the proper behaviour. The thing I did not like is that I used complicated naming standard for my classes.